# Django Foreign key constraint error on submitting a row

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I just created a Django Project and added 2 directly in mysql:

1) Financial Holdings (tbl_holdings)

2) Service Providers (tbl_holdings_service_providers)

Both of their Data Definitions in My Sql are:

> tbl_holdings

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_holdings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `service_provider` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `account_details` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_cost` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `current_value` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `item_code_UNIQUE` (`item_code`),
  KEY `fk_service_provider_name_idx` (`service_provider`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_service_provider` FOREIGN KEY (`service_provider`) REFERENCES `tbl_holdings_service_providers` (`provider_name`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> tbl_holdings_service_providers

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_holdings_service_providers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `provider_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `INDEX` (`provider_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I created the related model in Django models.py

```
class TblHoldings(models.Model):
    item_code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=5)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    service_provider = models.ForeignKey('TblHoldingsServiceProviders', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='service_provider',db_column='service_provider')
    account_details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    purchase_cost = models.IntegerField()
    current_value = models.IntegerField()
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Holding'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Holdings'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_holdings'

class TblHoldingsServiceProviders(models.Model):
    provider_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Lookup For Service Provider"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Lookup For Service Providers'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_holdings_service_providers'
```

and the code in admin.py is

```
@admin.register(TblHoldings)
class HoldingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('item_code', 'product_name', 'service_provider', 'current_value', 'created_at')
    ordering = ('purchase_date',)
    search_fields = ('product_name',)

@admin.register(TblHoldingsServiceProviders)
class HoldingsServiceProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'provider_name', 'created_at')
    ordering = ('created_at',)
    search_fields = ('provider_name',)
```

On trying to add a holding I get the below error: pertaining to the foreign key constraint

> IntegrityError at /admin/app_fin/tblholdings/add/ (1452, 'Cannot add
>   or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`_finance`.`tbl_holdings`, CONSTRAINT `fk_service_provider`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`service_provider`) REFERENCES
>   `tbl_holdings_service_providers` (`provider_name`) ON DELETE NO ACTION
>   ON UPDATE )') Request Method: POST Request
>   URL:  admin/app_fin/tblholdings/add/ Django
>   Version:  2.2.7 Exception Type:   IntegrityError Exception Value:  (1452,
>   'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`_finance`.`tbl_holdings`, CONSTRAINT `fk_service_provider`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`service_provider`) REFERENCES
>   `tbl_holdings_service_providers` (`provider_name`) ON DELETE NO ACTION
>   ON UPDATE )') Exception
>   Location: /root//venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py
>   in query, line 231 Python
>   Executable:   /root//venv/bin/python Python Version:  3.6.8
>   Python Path:   ['/root//project_', 
>   '/root//venv/lib/python36.zip', 
>   '/root//venv/libremoved/python3.6', 
>   '/root//venv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
>   '/usr/lib/python3.6', 
>   '/root/_fin/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages'] Server
>   time: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 09:51:28 +0000

Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the foreign key you are using is not a primary key. You can try this out

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_holdings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `service_provider` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `account_details` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_cost` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `current_value` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `purchase_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `item_code_UNIQUE` (`item_code`),
  KEY `fk_service_provider_name_idx` (`service_provider`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_service_provider` FOREIGN KEY (`service_provider`) REFERENCES `tbl_holdings_service_providers` (`provider_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```